# Add a new Entry in MS Project using vba problem

Tags: vba, ms-project

If i want add a new entry in project using vba the code will be:

```
prjApp.TableEdit Name:="&Entry", TaskTable:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True, NewName:="", NewFieldName:="Outline Code10", Width:=20, ShowInMenu:=True, LockFirstColumn:=True, DateFormat:=255, RowHeight:=1
prjApp.TableApply Name:="&Entry"
```

but if project is not in english but for example in italian you will get an error because instead of "&Entry" you will have "&Immissione".

It' would be nice be language-independent but how?

Comment: Can you find the table you want want in the Application.Tables collection? Maybe it's always in the same position in that collection?

Comment: The best solution is copy the table and apply a new name to the copy... then use the new table created. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not an answer to how, but it is not a good practice to modify the default tables. 
Instead I'd create a new table and view the way I want.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you want use the default table settings (Entry) you could use the Copy("Name") method and then use this new table.... thank you again